# SQL setting dictating how floats are stored

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Good day to all.  I fond an odd difference between my test environment and my production environment.  I have a table which stores data as a float.  I run the following script on both with different results:

```
insert into myTable(myFloat)
  select top 1 26.1295 as foo

Select myFloat from myTable
Server A = 26.1295
Server B = 26.129499435424805
```

Is there a difference between the server setup that would cause this?  any thoughts would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I guess it must be a setting in SQL Query Analyzer or the tool that you are using.

Comment: What tool are you using to retrieve and display the results?

Comment: Both systems are using MS Query Analyzer that ships with SQL 2000 Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are stored according to the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers), which is why this happens.

If you need the precision to that decimal point, use the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) data type (or `numeric`, same thing). Do note that it is a bit slower than a float, however, since computers can do floating point math natively, but some extra overhead goes into decimal/numeric calculations.

Comment: So is the difference that they are on different machines?  I know that floats for this use are "bad".  I inherited the system and can't change it at the moment.

Comment: @soultower: Are both tables of data type `float`? Or is one of data type `decimal`/`numeric`?

Comment: Both are float, created from the same script.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual data type, and how are you displaying the values? It might actually be the same value displayed in different ways.

If you mean the MSSQL data type `float`, that corresponds to the `double` data type in the .NET framework, it has a precision of about 15 digits.

If you mean the MSSQL data type `real`, that corresponds to the `float` data type in the .NET framework, it has a precision of about 7 digits.

As either data type has a limited precision, you can't expect to get the exact value back that you assign to it. The value stored is the closest value that the data type can represent, so it will often be rounded off where the precision ends. If you store the value 26.1295 in a single precision field, it may actually end up as 26.129499435424805 as that is as close that you can get with the precision of the field.

How you see the value when you get it back depends on how you display it. Usually the code that turns the value back into a text representation also has rounding in it so that it stops before the precision ends, and you never see the difference.

If you store the value as a single precision number in the database, but convert it to a double precision number when you read it from the database, you may see the value as it's stored instead of rounded at the edge of the precision. The widening conversion will increase the precision but it can not add any more information.

Comment: Both systems store as float length 8 precision 53.  The "real world" scenario is a view which calculates a benefit against a salary.  The benefit was 26.1295%.  The differing between the two systems was just enough and at a perfect threshold to cause the same application code to round up in one instance vs down in the other.  True difference of a penny, resulting app difference of 1 dollar (displayed).  in the grand scheme of things the overall effect in the app is small since it's the true value that is stored, not the display value.

Comment: if you are storing as float, your true value is not stored. If you are calculating on it, you have wrong calculations most likely.

Comment: @souLTower: If you are handling monetary values you should definitely not use floating point types for storage, but the Decimal data type.

Answer (score 0):

Never consider using float for anything that you will do calculations on. It is not an exact datatype and you will have errors in your calculations. You need to change your structure to use a numeric or decimal datatype (don't forget to allow a few extra places for doing division and multiplication on the values).

Comment: Floating point values are excellent for values that you do calculations on, as long as you want speed and don't expect an exact result.

Comment: A calculation without an exact result is useless says the former auditor. Maybe there are some scientific applications where approximation is needed but I know of no business applications. And you'd be surprised how fast all those approximations can add up to a serious financial error.